# I see "Class not found" alert on Facebook.login using Ionic 2

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2. I already installed cordova-plugin-facebook4 with `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`.

here is the piece of my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class CoreService {
    public fbLogin():void{
        Facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
            alert('Logged in');
        }).catch( (error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
```

and when I am calling `fbLogin` function I see alert with "Class not found" message.
[image]

I see this alert on simulator(Android 6.X) as well as on real device(Android 4.4). There is no error on console.

Answer (score 2):

I did `ionic platform remove android` then `ionic platform add android` and it solve the problem.